Why do certain structs generate new UUID() every time I open a view
I want to build an App that stores Reminders (e.g Quotes) and displays it on the ContentView. You can create own reminders or get them from another View that has an Array of Reminders stored that I manually typed in. But every time I add one from my ExploreView to the array that is on the ContentView I append a Struct with the UUID() of the Element from the Explore View. But when I go back into my exploreView from my ContentView all Elements have a new UUID
struct Reminder: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable{
    var id = UUID()
    var phrase: String
    var author: String

    init(phrase: String, author: String) {
        self.phrase = phrase
        self.author = author
        self.phrase.addQuotationMarks()
    }
}

class ExploreReminders {
    let exploreReminders: [Reminder] = [
        Reminder(phrase: "Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.", author: "Albert Einstein"),
        Reminder(phrase: "The only way to do great work is to love what you do.", author: "Steve Jobs"),
        Reminder(phrase: "Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans.", author: "John Lennon"),
        Reminder(phrase: "In three words I can sum up everything I've learned about life: it goes on.", author: "Robert Frost"),
        Reminder(phrase: "You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.", author: "Mae West"),
        Reminder(phrase: "Yesterday is history, tomorrow is a mystery, today is a gift of God, which is why we call it the present.", author: "Bil Keane")
    ]
    
}

import SwiftUI

struct ExploreView: View {
    @State var exploreReminders = ExploreReminders()
    @State var allReminders: AllReminder
    @State private var userSearch = ""
    
    
    var searchResults: [Reminder] {
        if userSearch.isEmpty{
            return exploreReminders.exploreReminders
        } else{
            let editedUserSearch = userSearch.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let searchResult = exploreReminders.exploreReminders.filter {
                let editedPhrase = $0.phrase.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                let editedAuthor = $0.author.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                
                return editedPhrase.contains(editedUserSearch) || editedAuthor.contains(editedUserSearch)
            }
            return searchResult
        }
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns:[
                    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100, maximum: 200), spacing: 20),
                    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100, maximum: 200), spacing: 20)
                ], spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(searchResults) { reminder in
                        NavigationLink{
                            ReminderDetailView(reminder: reminder, allReminders: allReminders)
                        } label:{
                            ReminderView(reminder: reminder, allReminders: allReminders)
                                 .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Explore")
            .searchable(text: $userSearch, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search for Phrases or Authors")
            
        }
        
        
    }
}

I tried to outsource the ExploreReminderArray to a outer class as you can see but that still didn't work.

I haven't verified this, hence a comment and not an answer, but you create a whole new set of ExploreReminders every time you create a new instance of the view. i.e. whenever the view gets redrawn. That means you get new UUID's. You need to use a proper model.

Every time you go to your explorer view you create a new instance of ExploreReminders and thus a new instance of the array exploreReminders with new objects. Perhaps make the array property static.

@JoakimDanielson making it static works. Thanks a lot
